# Highlight multiple lines between two search patterns in gvim

Tags: search, vim, highlight

I am trying to highlight multiple lines that match between two words which are present on two different lines.

***1.Todo***: used for the todo comments (ones that have "TODO: **something**" in them)
2.Comment: indicates a code comment.
3.Statement: a code statement like a for loop
4.Type: a user defined type generally
5.PreProc: a pre-processor statement like #include <**stdio**.h>

To highlight between todo and something on  single line we use 
/todo.*something

but to highlight between todo and stdio(which is present on 5th line) is there any command.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can make use `\_.` to include linebreaks. For the example `todo ... stdio`, you can try:

```
/todo\_.\{-}stdio
```

Comment: @EashwarGadanchi if Kent's answer has helped you, consider approving it as the accepted answer.